# vs code terminal console not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, terminal

so I installed the code runner extension and wanted to try javascript in vscode, to my suprise you cannot write in the output section so I switched to terminal. I right clicked my js file and chose 'open in integrated terminal', i wrote a snippet

`document.firstElementChild.lastElementChild.lastElementChild.lastElementChild.innerHTML = "Angela";`

and the first thing it showed me was this:
[angela-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPPVK.png)

so I cleaned it and wrote another code i.e fizzBuzz. when I run `fizzBuzz();` it tells me

> An expression was expected after '('.
> + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression

i don't know wth that means.
So then I tried This: `var heading = document.firstElementChild.lastElementChild.firstElementChild;` and when i call heading in the console this happens again: [heading-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5im2U.png)

my directory will be image 3. [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNdyL.png)

the code for fizzBuzz will also be here:

```js
var output = [];
var count = 1;

function fizzBuzz() {

  while (count <= 100) {

    if (count % 3 == 0 && count % 5 == 0) {
      output.push("fizzBuzz");
    } else if (count % 3 == 0) {
      output.push("fizz");
    } else if (count % 5 == 0) {
      output.push("buzz");
    } else {
      output.push(count);
    }
    count++;
  }
  console.log(output);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Hello</h1>

  <input type="checkbox">

  <button style="color: red" ;>Click Me</button>

  <ul>
    <li class="list">
      <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list">Second</li>
    <li class="list">Third</li>
  </ul>






  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please can someone help me with this. All of the above i tried in chrome console and it works. But i would love to work in vscode if possible.
Also i know this is all messy so please forgive my messiness, amateur things you know!
Thank you All.

Comment: So as i was researching this issue i found out that it could be node js that is interfering, meaning my vs code is trying to run server side code which doesn't have document model and that is why i am having reference error, so my question now is how do i fix that this? how do i pause node js or revert back if that is what the problem is? If that is not the problem however then I do not know what to do next.

Comment: turns out it's not as i just tried on another machine